# <video> tag and autoplay attribute: How to make it work on production?

Tags: html5-video, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to embed a video set with the `autoplay` on Prestashop 1.7 . I'm using the default editor with the following code:

```
<div class="owl-item" style="width: 100%;">
  <video width="100%" height="600" autoplay>
    <source src="/img/cms/myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </source>
  </video>
```

As soons as I publish it, it seems that Prestashop just compiles the code without the `autoplay`attribute. I noticed that it happens with other php based code. I don't know how to avoid it and can't understand why either.

Any thoughts? thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to disable the HTMLpurifier library from the settings? "Shop parameters > General"

Comment: It worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PrestaShop use a library called 'HTMLPurifier' that clean the potentially 'bad' html in the textarea that allows you to insert the text also as html.
This library clean the suspicious tags (or attribute) as iframe, autoplay, script, and many others.

Usually disabling it resolve the problem that the tags or the tag attribute disappears after saving :)

Enjoy